# Powershell Pipeline Variable No Output

Tags: powershell, variables, pipeline

I'm trying to get all the user photos from my office365 server. I need them to show in the Alias format which is firstname.lastname

`get-mailbox | % {Get-UserPhoto $_.alias} | % {Set-Content -path "c:\export\$($_.alias).jpg" -value $_.picturedata -Encoding byte}`

This works, but gives me First Name Last Name

Someone told me I need to pass mailbox parameters through the pipeline, to do what I want to do.

`get-mailbox -PipelineVariable Mailbox | % {Get-UserPhoto $Mailbox.alias} | % {Set-Content -path "c:\export\$($Mailbox.alias).jpg" -value $_.picturedata -Encoding byte}`

This is my new code, but it's not spitting out photos into directory. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot check this now, but I think this may work:

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object { 
    $photo = Get-UserPhoto -Identity $_.alias
    Set-Content -Path "c:\export\$($_.alias).jpg" -value $photo.picturedata -Encoding byte
}
```

Comment: I get this error over and over
`Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
 `